# Loading in i18n translations without showing translation ids

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-i18next

I've implemented i18next in my nextjs project, and I'm having the issue, that I can briefly see all the text-id's before the translations get fully loaded. Is there any way to avoid showing these text ID's as it causing a bit of flickering on load? It's especially obvious when refreshing the page quickly.

I have tried different ways with both useSuspense and wait in the config and App file. Currently this is what I have (translation files are located in public/locales/xx/translation.json):
i18n.jsx

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    react: {
      useSuspense: true
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

Usage:

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export default function Text () {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (<Text>{t('text.string.here')}</Text>)
```

App

```js
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import i18n from 'components/i18n'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  <Suspense fallback="loading">
    <Component {...pageProps}/>
  </Suspense>
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: You may want to consider looking into [`next-i18next`](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) as it's tailored for Next.js usage.